# Wrong value for statusBarOrientation on viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, viewwillappear, uistatusbar

I need to change the image background of a View depending on the orientation. For this, I am using the statusBarOrientation approach in `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(currentOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"PORTRAIT");
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(currentOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"LANDSCAPE");
    }   
}
```

The problem is that the console is always showing PORTRAIT, even when the iPad is held in landscape mode. The same code in `viewDidAppear` works correctly, but there is too late and the user can see the change of images. That makes me think that the correct state of statusBarOrientation is still not available in `viewWillAppear`, but I have read in some other questions that this code should work there.

Comment: What's even weirder is that in viewWillTransitionToSize: you can query the orientation, and if you rotate the phone twice (back to its viewDidLoad position), statusBarOrientation'll give you the correct answer. Even though it gave a different answer in viewDidLoad, and now the device is in the same orientation as then!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
int type = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (type == 1) {
        NSLog(@"portrait default");
    }else if(type ==2){
        NSLog(@"portrait upside");
    }else if(type ==3){
        NSLog(@"Landscape right");
    }else if(type ==4){
        NSLog(@"Landscape left");
    }
```

Comment: Ok, interesting... I read everywhere that the statusbar orientation approach is more reliable that the UIDevice one, but this is working like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: i searched everywhere...interfaceOrientation, statusBar all were returning wrong orientation , Then This solution worked +1..

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using the statusBarOrientation to determine the current orientation of the application. According to Apple's doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> The value of this property is a constant that indicates an orientation of the receiver's status bar. See UIInterfaceOrientation for details. Setting this property rotates the status bar to the specified orientation without animating the transition. If your application has rotatable window content, however, you should not arbitrarily set status-bar orientation using this method. The status-bar orientation set by this method does not change if the device changes orientation.

Try using the **interfaceOrientation** property of a UIViewController to get the orientation of the current application.

Comment: I used this approach because it's recommended in several answers here in Stackoverflow to get the orientation. With the [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] approach it worked. Reading the property interfaceOrientation worked as well.

Comment: The link to the Apple documentation doesn't say that you shouldn't be using it to determine current orientation. Can you give us a reference to a source that says why you shouldn't? In fact, Apple's sample code uses it: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Swift_AVCam_CameraViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Swift_AVCam_CameraViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_15 Cmd-F for statusbarOrientation. In fact, UIDevice orientation warns that it could be different from your UI's orientation, so judging by the docs, one should avoid it.

Comment: This gives issues on SOME devices. Thanks apple.

Comment: `interfaceOrientation` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful code snippet for logging the device's interfaceOrientation:

```
NSArray* orientations = @[ @"nothing", @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait", @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown", @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft", @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight”];
NSLog(@"Current orientation := %@", orientations[self.interfaceOrientation]);
```

Hope this helps someone out!